# How to launch Webviews in a coroutine

Tags: kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm a new Android developer and in a compose app I am trying to display a list web pages in a LazyRow, each of these webpages will be displayed within the LazyRow using AndroidView and Webview.
I really want to know if there is a way to launch the display of each webpage in a new coroutine.
Thank you.

Here is the lazyRow

```
@Composable
fun Pages(list:  List<Page>, resetEzySearUiState: () -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    resetEzySearUiState()
    LazyRow(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
            items(items = list, key = {item -> item.id}) {
                item -> WebPage(url = item.link)
        }
    }
}
```

When the function pages is called it will be supplied with a list of Page object which holds the url and id

Here is the Composable to display each web page

```
@Composable
fun WebPage(url: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val size = Size()
    val screenWidth = size.width()
    Card(modifier = modifier
        .width(screenWidth.dp)
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 8.dp)) {
            AndroidView(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            factory = {
                WebView(it).apply {
                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                    webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    loadUrl(url)
                }
            }, update = { it.loadUrl(url) }
        )
    }
}
```